# javascript - Jquery - remove option for multiple images preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first post, because I really stuck here..
I just learned to code and I have difficulty to add an option to remove images that already previewed.. Please help me to add the option to remove each image in the preview (for example add an "X" symbol in upper right of each image).

Thank you for the help..

Below is my HTML Code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Upload Foto </label>
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-large"></i> Upload Photos
            <%= file_field_tag "images[]", id: "gallery-photo-add", type: :file, multiple: true %>
        </span>
    </div> <div class="gallery"></div>
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }


                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
```

Comment: hey it's me again, is there anyone who could help me? thanks!